# Position de malheureusement

Tags: usage, négation, ordre-des-mots, adverbes

Dans une négation, quelle est la bonne position d'un adverbe comme *malheureusement* ?
Par exemple, la phrase

> Je suis désolé, je ne peux malheureusement pas vous donner de réponse.

est-elle correcte ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ta phrase est parfaitement correcte.

On peut aussi choisir cette forme :

> Je suis désolé mais malheureusement je ne peux pas vous donner de réponse.

Comment: Ou "*Malheureusement, je ne peux pas vous donner de réponse*" - so many possibilities